# Flexbox - Set flex item size based total number of items

Tags: html, css, reactjs, flexbox

I need some basic help with `flexbox`. The question has probably been asked, but I couldn't find it anywhere.

I have a container `div` set to `display: flex;` with an unknown amount of children, like so:

```
<div class="container">
 <div class="child">First child</div>
 <div class="child">Second child</div>
     ...
 <div class="child">Nth child</div>
</div>
```

Now, I need every child to have the same width. In order to do that, I was thinking to use `flex: 0 0 ?`. My **question** is what should I replace `?` with ? In an ideal world, I would set :

```
flex: 0 0 calc(100/n)%;
```

where `n` would be the amount of children. The thing is, I don't know `n` (how many children `<div class="container">` has) in advance.

PS: I'm developing an interface in ReactJS. I've only shown HMTL code for better readability. All solutions are welcome, but CSS-only are preferred to ReactJS ones.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this:

```css
#container {
  display: flex;
  border: 4px solid black;
  padding: 3px;
  width: 600px;
}

.box {
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  border: 2px solid grey;
  padding: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div class="box">We choose to go to the Moon...We choose to go to the Moon in this decade and do the other things, not because they are easy, but because they are hard.</div>
  <div class="box">Hello World</div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box">Never Gonna Give You Up, Never Gonna Let You Down</div>
 </div>
```

`flex: 1 1 0px` is shorthand for:

```css
flex-grow: 1;
flex-shrink: 1;
flex-basis: 0px;
```

The `flex-basis` sets them all to be the same initial width of nothing, then the equal amounts of `flex-grow`+`flex-shrink` cause them to expand to the same width, regardless of the contents.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works, but I can't really say why... ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: It's magic. I've added a little explanation at the end of the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think flex-grow: 1 is all you need to let all children **grow equally** to take up the available space.

If you want to use the shorthand `flex:`, you can skip the last property(basis). That will give it the value `auto`, and it will have the same effect as long as `flex-grow` is set to 1.

```css
.parent{
display:flex;
flex-direction: row;
background: green;
}
.parent div{
background: yellow;
flex-grow: 1;

/*flex:1 0;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
<div>A</div>
<div>A</div>
<div>A</div>
<div>A</div>
<div>A</div>
<div>A</div>
<div>A</div>
<div>A</div>
<div>A</div>
<div>A</div>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried this, but It doesn't work. Replace all your `A`'s by words of different lengths. The `flex-grow` property will distribute _remaining space_, not the actual width of the child. At least it's what happened when I tried it.